# Count and Where

Tags: group-by, where-clause, sql-order-by

Finding all the invoices from the billing city Brasilia, Edmonton, and Vancouver in descending order by invoice. Do I need the GROUP BY clause? I the WHERE function do I use AND between the cities or commas?

SELECT invoiceid,
customerid,
billingcity,
FROM invoices
WHERE billingcity
ORDER BY invoiceid

Tried the AND and comma between cities keep getting error.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT invoiceid, customerid, billingcity
FROM invoices
WHERE billingcity IN ('Brasilia', 'Edmonton', 'Vancouver')
ORDER BY invoiceid DESC
```